# What is the meaning of ‘in ten years’?

Tags: meaning

Our house is being decorated next summer for the first time in ten years.

What is the meaning of ‘in ten years’?

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple

It means that the person who is decorating his/her house has not done it for last ten(10) years and is doing it for 1st time

Comment: Why not use ‘within’ instead of ‘in’?  Because ‘in’ can express ‘in the future’.

Comment: You can use within but in is also appropriate as in the sentence "is being" is used which shows a present task

Comment: Suppose your sentence becomes "Our house is being decorated next summer for the first time in next ten years.". Then it just doesn't make sense

Comment: Why not use ‘in the last ten years’? Because ‘in ten years’ might be misunderstood as ‘ in the future ten years’.

Comment: Yes you can use "in last ten years" but even if you dont use last the sentence is not suited for "in the future ten years"

Comment: You can refer to this post for guide on where to use in and within  https://blogs.transparent.com/english/within-vs-with-in-vs-in/